# GridView + CursorAdapter + AsyncTask load image shifting randomly

Tags: android, gridview, android-asynctask, simplecursoradapter

I use SimpleCursorAdapter and GridActivity (extended Activity written by me based on ListActivity) to load music albums from MediaStore, and use AsyncTask load **each** album art .

I tried this in `bindView` or `getView`, like this:

```java
new AsyncAlbumArtLoader(viewholder.album_art, mShowFadeAnimation).execute(aid, width, height);
```

class `AsyncAlbumArtLoader`:

```java
private class AsyncAlbumArtLoader extends AsyncTask<Object, Void, Bitmap> {

    boolean enable_animation = false;
    private ImageView imageview;

    public AsyncAlbumArtLoader(ImageView imageview, Boolean animation) {

        enable_animation = animation;
        this.imageview = imageview;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {

        if (enable_animation) {
            imageview.startAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(),
                    android.R.anim.fade_out));
            imageview.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected Bitmap doInBackground(Object... params) {

        return MusicUtils.getCachedArtwork(getApplicationContext(), (Long) params[0],
                (Integer) params[1], (Integer) params[2]);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {

        if (result != null) {
            imageview.setImageBitmap(result);
        } else {
            imageview.setImageResource(R.drawable.albumart_mp_unknown_list);
        }
        if (enable_animation) {
            imageview.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            imageview.startAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(),
                    android.R.anim.fade_in));
        }

    }
}
```

But images shifting between gridview items randomly.

You can see screen record video [here](http://musicmod.tk/post/15933073355/g1-bug).

**edited** prevent this error by setTag() and getTag() is also no effect.

```java
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        View view = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);

        mAlbumCursor.moveToPosition(position);

        ViewHolder viewholder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();

        String album_name = mAlbumCursor.getString(mAlbumIndex);
        if (album_name == null || MediaStore.UNKNOWN_STRING.equals(album_name)) {
            viewholder.album_name.setText(R.string.unknown_album_name);
        } else {
            viewholder.album_name.setText(album_name);
        }

        String artist_name = mAlbumCursor.getString(mArtistIndex);
        if (album_name == null || MediaStore.UNKNOWN_STRING.equals(album_name)) {
            viewholder.artist_name.setText(R.string.unknown_artist_name);
        } else {
            viewholder.artist_name.setText(artist_name);
        }

        // We don't actually need the path to the thumbnail file,
        // we just use it to see if there is album art or not
        long aid = mAlbumCursor.getLong(mAlbumIdIndex);
        int width = getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.gridview_bitmap_width);
        int height = getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.gridview_bitmap_height);

        viewholder.album_art.setTag(aid);
        new AsyncAlbumArtLoader(viewholder.album_art, mShowFadeAnimation, aid, width, height).execute();

        long currentalbumid = MusicUtils.getCurrentAlbumId();
        if (currentalbumid == aid) {
            viewholder.album_name.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0, 0,
                    R.drawable.ic_indicator_nowplaying_small, 0);
        } else {
            viewholder.album_name.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0, 0, 0, 0);
        }

        return view;
    }


// FIXME image loaded some times incorrect
private class AsyncAlbumArtLoader extends AsyncTask<Object, Void, Bitmap> {

    boolean enable_animation = false;
    private ImageView imageview;
    private long album_id;
    private int width,height;

    public AsyncAlbumArtLoader(ImageView imageview, Boolean animation, long album_id, int width, int height) {

        enable_animation = animation;
        this.imageview = imageview;
        this.album_id = album_id;
        this.width = width;
        this.height = height;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {

        if (imageview.getTag() == null || (Long)imageview.getTag() != album_id) {
            return;
        }

        if (enable_animation) {
            imageview.startAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(),
                    android.R.anim.fade_out));
            imageview.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected Bitmap doInBackground(Object... params) {

        if (imageview.getTag() == null || (Long)imageview.getTag() != album_id) {
            return null;
        }

        return MusicUtils.getCachedArtwork(getApplicationContext(), album_id,
                width, height);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {

        if (imageview.getTag() == null || (Long)imageview.getTag() != album_id) {
            return;
        }

        if (result != null) {
            imageview.setImageBitmap(result);
        } else {
            imageview.setImageResource(R.drawable.albumart_mp_unknown_list);
        }
        if (enable_animation) {
            imageview.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            imageview.startAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(),
                    android.R.anim.fade_in));
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: You can view source code of this application [here](https://github.com/mariotaku/musicmod)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Problem is, that the AsyncTask don't know für which ImageView they where started, respectivley they overlap.

To prevent this you need to do the following:
In your `getView` Method (before calling the AsyncTask-Constructor you need so set a Tag to your ImageView: `myImageView.setTag(object)`. The best choice is, if you use the object from which getView gets its information. In you case i think it is the ArrayList with the Album-Information. Let' say `myImageView.setTag(myAlbumArray.get(position))` THE TAG MUST BE UNIQUE
Now add a new String 'tag' to your AsyncTask class and add `this.tag = imageview.getTag().toString()`.
Now finally add the test in your `onPostExecute`:

```
 if (imageview.getTag().toString().equals(tag)) {
// you got the right imageView, *your PostExecute Code* }
else {// wrong one, do nothing
}
```

Comment: I think my problem may not caused by this.

Comment: Well i got the same problem like shown in your video, and solved it with this code.

Comment: `new AsyncAlbumArt(imageview, false)` sets the only imageview for this task to operate. You can see my code `org.musicmod.android.activity.AlbumBrowserActivity`

Comment: But in your onPost you set ImageView's source to the Bitmap retreived in AsyncTask. And there is the Problem, this ImageView ist not necessary the same which you give in the AsyncTasks constructor. That is a known problem.

Comment: Sorry for the previous delayed reply. Thank you so much. I'll try it soon and give you feedback.

Comment: It don't work...I will post my getView method and modified code below.

Comment: Hm, don't see any error there. Maybe the error is in CachedArtowrk-method

Comment: Well, now my only resolution is update image without using asynctask. If you are not busy you could view my all source code to find getCachedArtWork method.

Comment: I found the reason that image shifting is garbage collector. Same problem is also happened when others try to load image in another thread.

Comment: Could you tell, how you fix it?

Comment: So tell us what the reason was and how to fix it please.